# Trying to get a innerhtml functionality to work in react todo list

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I am aiming for new tasks to show as user clicks "add task", simple I know, but still learning `react`.

My goal was to use a `ternary` operator until its no longer `null`, and then map through the array each time a user clicks add task.

**Issue**:
I believe the `renderTasks` array isn't set by the time it tries to map over it, I get an error...

```sh
renderTasks.map is not a function
```

Is there a way I could utilize the `useEffect` for what I am trying to do, or any better ideas that could help? Thanks

Here's the code snippet of `App.js`

```js
function App() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
  const [renderTasks, setRenderTasks] = useState(null);

  const handleAddTask = () => {
    setRenderTasks(tasks);
  };
  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    setTasks({
      ...tasks,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="overview">
        <label className="my-todos">My Todos</label>
        <div className="input-div">
          <div className="input-container">
            <label className="title-desc">Title</label>
            <input
              name="title"
              onChange={handleOnChange}
              className="input-values"
              type="text"
            ></input>
          </div>
          <div className="input-container">
            <label className="title-desc">Description</label>
            <input
              name="description"
              onChange={handleOnChange}
              className="input-values"
              type="text"
            ></input>
          </div>
          <button onClick={handleAddTask} className="add-task">
            Add Task
          </button>
        </div>
        {renderTasks !== null ? (
          <ul>
            {renderTasks.map((x) => {
              return <li>{x.title - x.description}</li>;
            })}
          </ul>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were few issues in your implementation like how you **destructing tasks**, trying to **access an object as an array** and **abusing the `useState`**. You don't need `useEffect` or two `useState` to do the trick.

```
import React from "react";
import React, { useState } from 'react';    
import "./style.css";

function App() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
  const task = {};

  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    task[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
  };

  const onClickHandler = (e)=>{
     (task.title) && setTasks( [...tasks, task]);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div className="overview">
        &nbsp;
        <label className="my-todos">My Todos</label>
        <div className="input-div">
          <div className="input-container">
            <label className="title-desc">Title</label>
            <input
              name="title"
              onChange={handleOnChange}
              className="input-values"
              type="text"
            ></input>
          </div>

          <div className="input-container">
            <label className="title-desc">Description</label>
            <input
              name="description"
              onChange={handleOnChange}
              className="input-values"
              type="text"
            ></input>
          </div>
          <button onClick={onClickHandler} className="add-task">
            Add Task
          </button>
        </div>
          <ul>
            {tasks.map((x) => {return <li>{x.title} - {x.description}</li> })}
          </ul>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: This helped, thanks. Can I ask what exactly is `task.title &&` doing on the onClickHandler?

Comment: Oh...It just to check is task object is not empty.if task object has a property called `title` , means that task object is not empty..In plain JavaScript, we are currently lacking a method to check whether object is empty or not...

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are initialising `tasks` to be an array, in `handleOnChange` you are setting it to an Object like this -

```
setTasks({
  ...tasks,
  [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
});
```

This same `tasks` object you are trying to set for `renderTasks` in `handleAddTask`. So `renderTasks` is assigned to an Object and not an array and only arrays have `map` function and hence you are facing the issue `renderTasks.map is not a function error`

Try doing

```
Object.keys(renderTasks).map((x) => {
          return <li>{x.title - x.description}</li>;
        })
```

Comment: I see how this could work also, problem is object.keys only returns the keys, I need the values of the keys. I suppose you could use object.values, but I did find another solution here `setRenderTasks([...renderTasks, tasks]);` I just set it as an array instead of an object and it worked perfectly.